# Suppress "Avoid unnamed object" warnings for function returns

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a log function that I sometimes pass the return of on to another function, and sometimes call alone

```
LogReturnStruct Log(string message) { writeToFile(message); return {message};);
```

this is because i sometimes want to log something is about to be attempted, as well as if it succeeded or not

```
void Handle(LogReturnStruct, statusCode)
{
    if(statusCode == valid)
        Log("sucess: "+ LogReturnStruct.message);
    else
        Log("failure: "+ LogReturnStruct.message);
}
```

So i can call something like this

```
Handle(Log("message"),funcThatMightFail());
```

and it will enforce logging before and after this call, and will log at least before even if the call raises an exception

I also want to be able to just log a message however

```
Log("message"); // alone call
```

However, no matter how i use `[[maybe_unused]]`, i can't seem to suppress the compiler warning

> "Avoid unnamed objects with custom creation and destruction"

is there a way to indicate this return value may be unused (and that's ok) without disabling the entire warning?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified, so the first message can appear either before or after the function call.

Comment: @molbdnilo wait really? i thought it was right to left

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Seems msvc from [Warning C26444](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/code-quality/c26444?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Since the warning is informing you of a case where an object is created then destroyed unused, you could create a variation of `Log` (with a different name, because you can't overload just on the return value) that does not return anything.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes this is what i ended up doing, probably a better solution than trying to suppress warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might use `[[gsl::suppress(es.84)]]`, but it should be used at call site :-/

MACRO can then help:

```
LogReturnStruct LogImpl(string message) { writeToFile(message); return {message}; }

#define Log(s) [[gsl::suppress(es.84)]] LogImpl(s)
```

Cleaner solution is to avoid the warning and create 2 functions (You already have them :) ) (but requires to change call sites):

```
void Handle(LogReturnStruct, statusCode)
{
    if(statusCode == valid)
        writeToFile("sucess: "+ LogReturnStruct.message);
    else
        writeToFile("failure: "+ LogReturnStruct.message);
}
```

and

```
Handle(Log("message"), funcThatMightFail());
```

Comment: Macros are a good solution here, the better solution was probably not trying to do this